# filling dropdownlistfor box with dynamic table data from popup window

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a popup window in which iam retrieving data in table format. in that popup window, i need to click a table row and that clicked data need to be filled in a dropdownlist. that dropdownlist values are also retrieved from the database, i tried some code , help me to find the answer.
 ihave created the new window using below function in js

```
function opentestname() {
    window.open('testsearch', 'newwindow',
                config = 'height=300,width=500,left=50,top=205,down=25,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
}
```

**my main page where iam having dropdownlist**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.testname, Model.testname, new { @id = "test", @name = "test", @class = "form-control" })
```

**my popup window**

```
<table id="myTable">
                    <tr class="header">
                        <th style="width:60%;"> CODE </th>
                        <th style="width:60%;"> DESCRIPTION</th>
                        <th style="width:60%;">OPTION</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var items in Model)
                    {
                        <tr name="code">
                            <td >@items.code</td>
                            <td class="filter">@items.desc</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="fillparent(this)";>FILL</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
```

**my fillparent()is like**

```
    function fillparent()
{
    var input = document.getElementsByName("code").innerHTML;

    alert(input);
```

> //i dont know how to get the dynamic data by name and fill it in the
>   dropdownlistfor,
>   help me, 
>   Thanks,
>   shankiyan

Comment: send data to fillparent function or make an ajax call to get data from db and fill dropdown

Comment: CAN YOU EXPLAIN HOW TO CALL , IM NEW TO THIS